# Stuck in Tutorial Doctrine2: "class Product is not a valid entry or mapped super class"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Trying to do the tutorial: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/docs/en/tutorials/getting-started.rst#id3

when executing `$ php create_product.php ORM` I get the error message:

> class Product is not a valid entry or mapped super class

This is create_product.php

```
<?php
// create_product.php
require_once "bootstrap.php";
$newProductName = $argv[1];
$product = new Product();
$product->setName($newProductName);
$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();
echo "Created Product with ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";
```

And the bootstrap.php is

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=doctrine2;host=any.where.nl',
        'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                )
//      'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
//  'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);
// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

My Products.php is an exact copy as in the tutorial and located in `/src/Project.php`

Any idea why the error-message says that Product.php is not valid entity? And how to solve it?
Best regards,
Tim van Steenbergen

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't put @Entity annotation, the example is missing it. Try this:

```
/**
* @Entity 
* @Table(name="product")
*/
```

Comment: Correct!!! Thanks Zeljko. Not nice when the tutorials are 90% correct. Onwards to the next bug!!!

Answer (score -2):

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity 
* @ORM\Table(name="bugs")
*/
```

in the context of Doctrine 2 manual. Mentioned manual contain wrong code in the entity Bug, not in the entity Product now.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What's the reason for creating a table named `bugs`?

Comment: Mentioned manual contain wrong code in the entity Bug, not in the entity Product now.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it