# stuck on doctrine2 tutorial error "No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Product". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key. "

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

After copy-pasting the example as is on the [page](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) I am getting this error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                
    No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Product". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

I searched a bit and [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357843/stuck-in-tutorial-doctrine2-class-product-is-not-a-valid-entry-or-mapped-super) that an entity annotation was missing from the code so I ended up with this code:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php

/**
* @Entity 
* @Table(name="Product")
* property int $id
* property string $name
*/

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
// or if you prefer yaml or XML
//$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
//$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yaml"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/db.sqlite',
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

The product creator is also  taken from the tutorial:

```
// create_product.php
require_once "bootstrap.php";


$newProductName = $argv[1];

$product = new Product();
$product->setName($newProductName);

$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Created Product with ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";
```

The Product is defined here:

```
<?php
/**
* @Entity 
* @Table(name="Product")
* property int $id
* property string $name
*/

// src/Product.php
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

I also tried the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168364/symfony2-and-doctrine2-no-identifier-primary-key-specified-for-entity-x-ever) though they did not give me any result.
I am very new to doctrine so do you have any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer [here](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys)

It seems that the php mapping was not correct after adding:

```
   /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
```

instead of:

```
* @var integer $id
```

to the Product class it worked.

Comment: Keep in mind that your problem was not caused by `@var` annotation. The annotations in your opening post are defined in Symfony style, using an alias `ORM` for imported namespace `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`. Since you're using Doctrine as a standalone vendor, you do not need `@ORM` prefix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I find it very hard to go around doctrine documentation actually it seems that there is not one place where one can start. I plan to use it with php any mysql Is there any link you could recommend for me to read?

Comment: I believe the documentation as it is now, is more than enough to get you started. All you need to know about Doctrine, should be found in there. You can always take another look here for questions tagget with [doctrine2](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[doctrine2]+is%3Aq).